# IAM role that only allows objects to be written to / read from a specific sub-folder in an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cli

#### Summary

As mentioned above, I want to create an IAM role that can ONLY read / write objects to a SPECIFIC sub-folder in the S3 bucket.

However, I'm unable to despite following the examples [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html#condition-key-bucket-ops-2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63094998/16409315)

#### Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:prefix": "levelOne=A/levelTwo=B/levelThree=C"
                }
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*",
                "S3:Put*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::insert_bucket_name",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:prefix": "levelOne=A/levelTwo=B/levelThree=C"
                }
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*",
                "S3:Put*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::insert_bucket_name",
            "Effect": "Deny"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Testing setup

##### AWS config file

```
[profile mybucketrole]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::insert_account_id:role/insert_role_name
source_profile = default
```

##### Test command

```
aws s3api put-object 
--bucket insert_bucket_name
--key levelOne=A/levelTwo=B/levelThree=C/123456789.jsonl
--profile mybucketrole
```

I would expect that the above command succeeds since I'm writing an object to the `levelOne=A/levelTwo=B/levelThree=C` prefix, but I keep getting an

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

NOTE: I set up CloudTrail for my S3 bucket to verify that the intended role is being used by the test command (and indeed it is)

#### Other things I've tried

- Replacing `StringEquals` + `StringNotEquals` with `StringLike` + `StringNotLike` (respectively) per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63094998/16409315)
- Changing the resources to

  ```
  "Resource": [
     "arn:aws:s3:::insert_bucket_name",
     "arn:aws:s3:::insert_bucket_name/*"
  ]
  ```

What am I missing!?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 buckets are private by default. Therefore, there is no need to use `Deny` unless you are wanting to override permissions that were otherwise granted by another IAM policy (eg preventing an Admin who has access to *all* S3 buckets from accessing an HR confidential bucket).

Therefore, you could use a policy like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*",
                "S3:Put*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::insert_bucket_name/levelOne=A/levelTwo=B/levelThree=C/*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the behavior I wanted with the following permissions policies and CDK code.

NOTE:

- All of the following are role-based policies
- The bucket policy was kept empty

#### WRITE policies

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "s3:Put*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::insert_bucket_name/level_one=A/level_two=B/level_three=C/*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### READ policies

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "s3:Get*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::insert_bucket_name/level_one=A/level_two=B/level_three=C/*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        // NOTE: 
        // I had to be permissive here because otherwise, S3 will return an AccessDenied error instead of NoSuchKey when requesting nonexistent S3 objects. 
        // See the CDK code comments for details
        {
            "Action": "s3:List*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::insert_bucket_name",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### CDK code

```
return new Role(this, roleName, {
            roleName: roleName,
            assumedBy: new CompositePrincipal(new AccountPrincipal(props.stageProps.awsAccountId)),
            maxSessionDuration: Duration.hours(12),
            inlinePolicies: {
                "READ": new PolicyDocument({
                    statements: [
                        new PolicyStatement({
                            effect: Effect.ALLOW,
                            actions: ["s3:Get*"],
                            resources: [
                                new Array(
                                    this.[insert_bucket_variable].bucketArn,
                                    "levelOne=A",
                                    "levelTwo=B",
                                    "levelThree=C",
                                    "*",
                                ).join("/")
                            ],
                        }),
                        new PolicyStatement({
                            effect: Effect.ALLOW,
                            actions: ["s3:List*"],
                            resources: [
                                // First off, our resource here has no wildcards because the ListBucket API action (i.e. the API behind our favorite ListObjectsV2 boto3 call)
                                // acts on the bucket resource itself vs. object resources (like the (Get|Put)Object API actions). 
                                // However, we don't restrict visibility here because if we do, we'll see AccessDenied errors
                                // if/when we make a GetObject API call against the bucket for a nonexistent object 
                                // (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56027548/16409315). That would be SUPER confusing to 
                                // debug so we want to avoid it -- even if it means that this IAM role can 
                                // list collections of converted labels from other labeling sources. That being said, this role still 
                                // wouldn't be able to actually download any of those collections because of the s3:Get* permissions so it's not a huge concession.
                                this.[insert_bucket_variable].bucketArn,
                            ],
                        }),
                    ]
                }),
                "WRITE": new PolicyDocument({
                    statements: [
                        new PolicyStatement({
                            effect: Effect.ALLOW,
                            actions: ["s3:Put*"],
                            resources: [
                                new Array(
                                    this.[insert_bucket_variable].bucketArn,
                                    "levelOne=A",
                                    "levelTwo=B",
                                    "levelThree=C",
                                    "*",
                                ).join("/")
                            ],
                        }),
                    ]
                })
            },
        });
```